# Qemu adjusting microphone

Tags: nvidia, microphone, qemu

I have a qemu virtual machine with vfio vga passthrough.
When I start it my microphone adjusts to 100% but I only when I have the Nvidia drivers installed on my virtual machine (I'm not sure if thats the reason but it seems so).
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the line `-device hda-microphone` which emulates a microphone caused this, because Windows sets the microphone to 100% and this seems to change the microphone settings for the host. Nvida drivers have nothing to do with this.